# Spark Dataset<Row> to ArrayList Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataset which holds values I want to output to a GUI.
In the past I would use a

```
List<someObject>
```

I would like to maintain such a structure if possible, however not hardset on it if other solutions are available.

The columns of the Dataset row are

```
x:y:z:t
```

I tried creating a class with the schema of the output of Dataset subDf and then create a list

```
List<SinglePoint>aList=subDf.as(Encoders.bean(SinglePoint.class)).collectAsList();
```

But this crashes with a error hard to interpret

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while
>   decoding: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.Exception: failed to compile:
>   org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java',
>   Line 27, Column 60: No applicable constructor/method found for zero
>   actual parameters; candidates are: "database.util.SinglePoint(int,
>   int, int, int)" /* 001 */ public java.lang.Object generate(Object[]
>   references) { /* 002 */   return new
>   SpecificSafeProjection(references);

I also tried

```
List<String>listTwo=subDf.map(row->row.mkString(),Encoders.STRING()).collectAsList()
```

But this did not have the desires structure to put into a GUI.

How can I convert a Dataset into an inter able list?

Comment: did you ever figure it out?